# Is Tor sandboxed on mac os x?

Tags: configuration

I'm concerned that running a Tor relay may open my machine to attack vectors from bugs (there are always bugs) in the daemon. Using the default installer, will Tor run in an account with limited permissions on Mac OS X (network only?) or do I either need to learn how to configure this myself or run Tor on a separate machine to limit my exposure.